# How to get information in div tag with html.parser?

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have a html tree where needed price is inside div tag and under the span tag. My code printing an empty value. How to I get needed price?

```html
<div class='card-product__price'>
    <span class='card-product__price-old>Old price is here></span>
        'Needed price is here'
</div>
```

```py
class Parser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if (not self.price_is_found and
            'class' not in self._product_info and
            tag == 'div'):
        attrs = dict(attrs)
        if attrs.get('class') == 'card-product__details':
            self.is_price_field = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if (not self.price_is_found and
            self.is_price_field and
            'class' not in self._product_info):
        self.lst.append(data)
        self._product_info['price'] = re.sub('[^\d+]', '', data)
        self.price_is_found = True
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated version :**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<div class="card-product__price"> <span class="card-product__price-old">Old price is here</span> "Needed price is here" </div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('div', {'class': 'card-product__price'}).text
print(price)
```

This will print out the string "Needed price is here".
You can also use the css selector to get the desired value in a more elegant way.

```
price = soup.select_one('.card-product__price').text
```

You can also use PyQuery library it uses jquery like syntax to get the desired value.

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

doc = pq(html)
price = doc('.card-product__price').text()
```

**If you want to use html.parser then try this out.**

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class PriceParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_price_tag = False
        self.price = ""

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrs = dict(attrs)
        if tag == 'div' and attrs.get('class') == 'card-product__price':
            self.in_price_tag = True

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_price_tag:
            self.price = data
            self.in_price_tag = False

html = '<div class="card-product__price"> <span class="card-product__price-old">Old price is here</span> "Needed price is here" </div>'
parser = PriceParser()
parser.feed(html)
print(parser.price)
```

**If you want to put all div texts into a list then try this out.**

```
class PriceParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_price_tag = False
        self.price = ""
        self.divs_text = []  # Initialize an empty list to store div text

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrs = dict(attrs)
        if tag == 'div':
            if attrs.get('class') == 'card-product__price':
                self.in_price_tag = True
            else:
                self.in_price_tag = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.in_price_tag:
            self.price = data
            self.divs_text.append(data)  # Append the text of the div element to the list
            self.in_price_tag = False
```

Then use this parser to parse your HTML and extract the needed price.

```
html = '<div class="card-product__price"> <span class="card-product__price-old">Old price is here</span> "Needed price is here" </div>'
parser = PriceParser()
parser.feed(html)
print(parser.price)
print(parser.divs_text)
```

Comment: It works. But it shows old info...not what I need

Comment: Yes, I used pyquery, but the task is to extract the value with html.parser. Is it possible?

Comment: Check the edit I added about html.parser

Comment: Now it works like my code, showing an empty string. Is it possible to put all div text inside a list?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. See the changes I added.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class PriceParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_price_tag = False
        self.prices = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrs = dict(attrs)
        if tag == 'div' and attrs.get('class') == 'card-product__price':
            self.in_price_tag = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'div' and self.in_price_tag:
            self.in_price_tag = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        data = data.strip()
        if self.in_price_tag:
            self.prices.append(data)

html = '<div class="card-product__price"> <span class="card-product__price-old">Old price is here</span> "Needed price is here" </div>'
parser = PriceParser()
parser.feed(html)
print(parser.prices[-1])  # <-- the needed price is the last element of the array
```

Prints:

```
"Needed price is here"
```